# DirichletCondition doesn't always work with RegionBoundary

Tags: differential-equations, regions, finite-element-method

I am trying to solve the heat equation on a circle with a square shaped hole in it. It works:

```
With[{outer = Disk[], inner = Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}]},
 sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary@outer],
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y] == 
      1, (Abs[x] == 1/2 && Abs[y] <= 1/2) || (Abs[y] == 1/2 && 
        Abs[x] <= 1/2)]},
   u, {x, y} \[Element] RegionDifference[outer, inner]]]

(* InterpolatingFunction object *)

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] Disk[], 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"]
```

[image: debatably pretty plot]

However, when I try to make the inner boundary condition less verbose using `RegionBoundary`, it fails with an (apparently erroneous) error message:

```
With[{outer = Disk[], inner = Rectangle[{-1/2, -1/2}, {1/2, 1/2}]},
 sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0,
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary@outer],
    DirichletCondition[
     u[x, y] == 1, {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary@inner]},
   u, {x, y} \[Element] RegionDifference[outer, inner]]]

(* NDSolveValue::bcnop "No places were found on the boundary where \
{x,y}\[Element]Line[{{-(1/2),-(1/2)},{1/2,-(1/2)},{1/2,1/2},{-(1/2),1/\
2},{-(1/2),-(1/2)}}] was True, so DirichletCondition[u==1,{x,y}\
\[Element]Line[{{-(1/2),-(1/2)},{1/2,-(1/2)},{1/2,1/2},{-(1/2),1/2},{-\
(1/2),-(1/2)}}]] will effectively be ignored" *)
(* another InterpolatingFunction *)
```

[image: an even less pretty plot]

And indeed the solution does not seem to make use of that condition, but I can't figure out why it doesn't, or what I should change to make it work.

Comment: `DirichletCondition[u[x, y] == 1, {x, y} \[Element] RegionBoundary@inner // N]` works better.

Answer (score 11):

If you use [`ToElementMesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToElementMesh.html), you can capture the features of the rectangle much better.

```
(*Import required FEM package*)
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"];
With[{outer = Disk[], inner = Rectangle[{-1 / 2, -1 / 2}, {1 / 2, 1 /
           2}]},
 (mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[
              outer, inner]])["Wireframe"]
 ]
```

[image: Wire mesh]

If you use the FEM mesh and replace `RegionBoundary` with `RegionMember` for the inner surface, then you will get the solution you desire.

```
With[{outer = Disk[], inner = Rectangle[{-1 / 2, -1 / 2}, {1 / 2, 1 /
           2}]},
 mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[
            outer, inner]];
     sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
             u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} ∈ RegionBoundary @ outer],
     DirichletCondition[u[
               x, y] == 1, {x, y} ∈ RegionMember @ inner]
    }, u, {x, y} ∈ mesh]
 ]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
     ]
```

[image: Solution]

Finally, `RegionBoundary` may be used if you use a real number to define the rectangle. For example:

```
With[{outer = Disk[], inner = Rectangle[{-1./ 2, -1 / 2}, {1 / 2, 1 /
           2}]},
 mesh = ToElementMesh[RegionDifference[
            outer, inner]];
     sol = NDSolveValue[{
    Laplacian[u[x, y], {x, y}] == 0, 
    DirichletCondition[
             u[x, y] == 0, {x, y} ∈ RegionBoundary @ outer],
     DirichletCondition[u[
               x, y] == 1, {x, y} ∈ RegionBoundary @ inner]
    }, u, {x, y} ∈ mesh]
 ]

DensityPlot[sol[x, y], {x, y} ∈ mesh, 
 ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"
     ]
```

[image: Solution with region boundary]